# select2 ajax not firing up

Tags: javascript, ajax, triggers, jquery-select2

i'm using Select2 4.0.3 for getting list of client.
when i use the code in https://select2.github.io/examples.html :

```
    `$ajax= $(".ClientSearchSc");
/* recherche select2 + ajax */
$ajax.select2({
    ajax:{
        url: url+"/ajax/Cmd/Clients.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 0,
        data: function (params) {
            console.log(params.term);
            return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        }
        ,
        processResults: function (data,params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data,
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true

    },
    minimumInputLength: 1
    ,
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    templateResult: clientiFormatResult,
    templateSelection: clientiFormatSelection
});`
```

when i look in Networks in chrome console i d'ont find Client.php !!! and always No result found in select2

Answer (score 0):

after 8 days of reaserch i find the probleme:

```
Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
```

The problème was js dateTimePicker plugin of jquery !!!!!!!!

Comment: emm even when i remove i find a second probleme : Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Comment: Hi, @Funpro -- Did you fix this by just removing the datetimepicker plugin or did you have to do some extra settings? I removed datetimepicker and ajax is still not firing.